# Javascript why (b + 1)-- wrong

Tags: javascript, increment, decrement

Javascript

Why upper section is ok but lower section not run. I would like to know the logic behind.

```
let b = 5;  //upper section
b + 1;
b--;
console.log(b);

(b + 1)--;  //lower section
console.log(b);
```

Comment: Because the `--` operator has to update the variable that you apply it to. But `(b + 1)` is not a variable. So there is no place to store the result of the `--` operation. It's like you are writing `(b + 1) = (b + 1) - 1;`, which is wrong because what's on the left side of the `=` is not a variable where the result can be stored.

Comment: Simple and direct explanation. I got it now. Thanks Jesper.

Answer (score 1):

The `--` operator takes a variable (or property), gets the value from it, subtracts 1 from it, *stores the result in the variable* then evaluates as the result.

`b` is a variable.

`(b + 1)` is not a variable. It an expression. You can't store anything in `(b + 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

`b + 1` is not *doing* anything. It's not *changing* anything. It's just an expression resulting in the value `6`.

So your line of `b + 1;` is equivalent to writing `6;`. Doesn't hurt, but doesn't change anything in your program either.

But the `--` operator is supposed to *change* something. Decrement the value of a *variable*. That means it needs a variable it can change. `6` is not a variable. It's a constant. You cannot decrement a constant.

Answer (score 1):

Operators `++` and `--` work only with variables.

It's not possible to run neither `1--` nor `1++`.

Comment: *"...only with variables."* Or properties, or parameters (but parameters are basically variables). :-) But I *think* that's the full list.

Answer (score 1):

`--` decrement the value of a variable so it is smaller than before. `b+1=5` so `5--` doesn't make any sense, as `5` is a constant and can't be decremented

Answer (score 0):

`b--;` is a shorthand way of writing `b = b - 1;`.

`(b + 1)--;`, therefore, is a shorthand way of writing `b + 1 = b + 1 - 1;`, which isn't syntactically valid since it's an assignment statement with an expression on the left side.

Comment: `(b + 1)--` is, itself, syntactically invalid. I really like your way of explaining the problem, but I think I'd avoid doing the expansion and *then* saying it's invalid syntax, since that says you're applying syntax rules to your expansion. *(**Not** my downvote. The reverse, actually.)*

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was trying to explain the underlying reasoning why `(any expression)--` is syntactically invalid.. it's shorthand for nonsense.

Answer (score -2):

Although you are asking for JavaScript, here is a document that describe varies types of values: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category

The reason the why upper section could be run, is b is a lvalue, which could be perform pre-inc/post-inc (any assignment); for (b + 1), it will be evaluated to a rvalue, not a lvalue, trying to assign rvalue a new value will throw an error, just like you assign a new value to a literal.